# need url querystring matching value inside Request object

Tags: php, silex

in my silex application, here is a sample controller code:

```
$api->match('/product/{id}', function(Request $request, $id) use ($api) {
   //my code here
})->method('DELETE');
```

Here I want to pass this url "/product/5?/testpara=myvalue" and retrieve the 'testpara' parameter's value using the '$request' object. Is it possible? If yes, How?

Problem is, I don't get that value even using $_REQUEST["testpara"].

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. You need a query parameter, so you can access it via the query parameterbag:

```
$request->query->get("testpara");
```

Just like the way you can access post variables via `$request->request->get()`.

Comment: Thanks. However, seems like it is not working to me. Is there any specific part where I should look into? I am new in silex and thus a little confused how to start debugging about it.

Comment: Is it in `$request->query->all()`?

Comment: nope. THis is the most frustrating part that, it doesn't even showing up in $_REQUEST/$_GET etc variables as well. Only I can see it in $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] variable.

Comment: Do you have QSA in your rewrite rule?

Comment: OK, great, found it. I had .htaccess rule as "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /default/web/index.php?/$1 [L]" and had to change it to "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /default/web/index.php/$1 [L]" . This new version is working for me now. Hope it won't break anything, right?

Comment: Also add the QSA (query string append) flag.

Answer (score 0):

$_REQUEST is a litlle outdated, you might want to try $_GET['testpara']

But the answer is your URL has a typo its /product/5/?testpara=myvalue instead of /product/5?/testpara=myvalue

Comment: That's not entirely - $_REQUEST simply contains all get, post and cookie data (in the order defined in php.ini).

Comment: Ok i should be a little more specific, but what I tried to say is that because of all those data in $_REQUEST, there is a chance that the data you want is not the same as the data that is provided.

Comment: I guess what @VictorLap is trying to say is that modifying `$_GET` and/or `$_POST` elements at runtime, those changes will not reflect in `$_REQUEST`. The vice versa is also applicable. If you need to evaluate only $_GET and $_POST ( _without $_COOKIE_ ), `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is a better alternative than `$_REQUEST ` from my point of view.